# Capturing IP address of web stream with StreamReader returning too much data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this piece of code:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead("http://url/getAddress.html");
string text = "";
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
     text = reader.ReadToEnd();
     reader.Close();
}
```

The result of this in HTML is an IP Address, but when i try to save this result in a database, the result that returns is the whole html page of the web request.
What am i doing wrong?

Example:

**text** has the result

if i do a `Response.Write(text);` it returns: **111.222.33.3**

if i try to save the variable **text** which returns the value, this will save the whole html content from the web request page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static String GetIP()
{
    String ip = 
        HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return ip;
}
```

i've found this solution, is perfect for what i want

Answer (score 4):

You realize that if you write to the `Response` object, that's going to format HTML on the web page?  That just formats the HTML you received from the web page.  You need to parse the HTML you get to get the actual data you're looking for, in the format you want it.

Comment: yes i know, thats an example, it was only to see if that returns the right result!
i tried to write in a label, and it works perfectly, but when i try to save, it saves the whole html page, and no IP Address

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano: did you try to save it to a file?

Comment: Why do you think what is displayed in the Response isn't the entire web page as well?  Did you View Source in the browser?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: nop! i have no interest to save ip addresses to a file!

Comment: Saving it to file is just to test the output and be able to see the whole thing for what it is. You don't need to make that it's permanent home.

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano: I know that! This is only to see that the content of the variable is not only the address (as you insist to claim) but also, the outer html.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: the result is only a <span> element

Comment: Write what in a label?  If you write HTML into a label it will be formatted when it's displayed in the browser.  That's what browsers do with HTML data.  It's *not* going to look the same as you view it in a debugger...

Comment: well, i'll try it to save to a file!

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano If you write a <span> element to Response, you won't see "<span>" in the browser...

Comment: is there any other good solution to get the client ipaddress?!

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano: It's really not clear what the problem is here.  When you get the response from the `WebRequest`, what is the actual value of `text`?  Not what displays in some UI, but when debugging what is the *actual value* of the variable?  Then what do you do to save it to the database?  (That code isn't included in the question.)